# Как задать отступ снизу у кнопки?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Используются Яндекс.Карты 2.1.
Как можно задать отступ снизу у кнопки, чтобы при их расположении в несколько строк они не "прилипали" друг к другу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Насколько мне известно, использование кнопок в несколько строк - это непредусмотренный вариант использования контролов в API Яндекс.карт. Там подойдет использования абсолютного позиционирования он краев карты (тоже задается через опции).